# iOS how to fix "HKSampleQuery Error reactivating query - Query already exists"?

Tags: multithreading, ios14, healthkit, hksamplequery

I'm pulling data from iOS HealthKit in a multi-threaded fashion. I have about 1000 queries prepared for various sample types (3 years of data in 1 day increments). There may be overlapping requests for data between different app components.

The code has a bug where some queries never execute. Apple provides this error message.

HKSampleQuery 8F9ED0 QoS=Default state=active>: `Invalid query activation state upon completing connection`
`HKSampleQuery`  QoS=Default state=deactivated>: `Error reactivating query:` Error Domain=com.apple.healthkit Code=100 "Query 'AF837C4C-6559-404F-8D7C-7226C0CD9216' `already exists`" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Query 'AF837C4C-6559-404F-8D7C-7226C0CD9216' already exists}